# AngularJs GPS access denied in other state

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs, cordova, gps

I'm working on a Cordova app and I use different AngularJs states.
If I call in the first state geolocation.watchposition it works perfect, but if I call it in the second state, I get access denied...

I change the states with a Button. No matter, which state I start first, the first one has GPS, the second one don't.

**EDIT:** I should mention, that its working in a browser, but not on my android device.

Do you know why?

index.js

```
.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $stateProvider
    .state('app', {
      url: '/app',
      templateUrl: 'templates/main_menu.html',
      controller: 'AppCtrl'
    })

   .state('map', {
       url: '/map',
       templateUrl: 'templates/map.html',
       controller: 'MapCtrl'
   });

   //First State
   $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/app');
});
```

controller.js

```
.controller('AppCtrl', function ($scope, $rootScope, $ionicHistory, $http, $window) { 
  $scope.accPos = function () {
      var id, target, options;

      function success(pos) {
          alert("Pos: " + pos.coords.latitude + " " + pos.coords.longitude);
      }

      function error(err) {
          alert('ERROR(' + err.code + '): ' + err.message);
      }

      options = {
          enableHighAccuracy: false,
          timeout: 6000,
          maximumAge: 0
      };

      id = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(success, error, options);
   };

   $scope.accPos();
}

//Looks exactly the same
.controller('MapCtrl', function ($scope, $rootScope, $ionicHistory, $http, $window) { ... }
```

Comment: You should implement the geolocation functionality in a service, so you could share the location to any view. What errors do you get in the error callback? Any other extra information

Comment: Yes, I did it with a servie now, but i wondered, why i cant use it in an other state :/
I got an Error 1: permission denied...

Comment: Not familiar with the plugin implementation but most likely there is a callback that is invoked when the native side has delivered new data, and the callback is the other view. Maybe you need to clear the watch in the first view before moving to the next.

Comment: I'll try it later, but how do i clear the watch? :)

Comment: [clearWatch](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/cordova-plugin-geolocation/index.html#navigatorgeolocationclearwatch)

Comment: I'd use an angular version - based on my experience it's always fishy to use something in angular what cannot be injected. Take a look at this: https://github.com/ninjatronic/ngGeolocation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should really move this kind of code to a service so it can be shared among your controllers. On top of that, you could utilize the ui-router's [resolve](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#resolve) functionality to resolve the GPS location for each state that needs it.

For example:

service.js

```
.factory('GeoLocationService', function ($window) { 
    var id, target, options, lastPosition;
    options = {
        enableHighAccuracy: false,
        timeout: 6000,
        maximumAge: 0
    };

    var geoLocationService = {
        startWatching: startWatching,
        stopWatching: stopWatching,
        getLastPosition: getLastPosition,
        options: options
    };  
    startWatching();
    return geoLocationService;

    function getLastPosition() {
        return lastPosition;
    }

    function startWatching() {
        id = $window.navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(success, error, options);
    }

    function stopWatching() {
        $window.navigator.geolocation.clearWatch(id);
    }

    function success(pos) {
        lastPosition = pos;
        alert("Pos: " + pos.coords.latitude + " " + pos.coords.longitude);
    }

    function error(err) {
        alert('ERROR(' + err.code + '): ' + err.message);
    }
});
```

index.js

```
.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $stateProvider
    .state('app', {
      url: '/app',
      templateUrl: 'templates/main_menu.html',
      controller: 'AppCtrl',
      resolve: {
         location: function(GeoLocationService){
            return GeoLocationService.getLastPosition();
         }
      }
    })

   .state('map', {
       url: '/map',
       templateUrl: 'templates/map.html',
       controller: 'MapCtrl',
       resolve: {
         location: function(GeoLocationService){
            return GeoLocationService.getLastPosition();
         }
      }
   });

   //First State
   $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/app');
});
```

controller.js

```
.controller('AppCtrl', function ($scope, $rootScope, $ionicHistory, $http, $window, GeoLocationService, location) {
    // show the location at start
    alert("Pos: " + location.coords.latitude + " " + location.coords.longitude);

    // maybe watch the location from the service
    $scope.$watch(function () {
        return GeoLocationService.getLastPosition();
    },
    function (newValue, oldValue) {
        if (newValue !== oldValue) {
            // do something
        }            
    }, true);
}
```

Note that this code is completely untested. I'm just trying to get the idea across.

Cheers!

Comment: Thank you, I did it almost like this, and it works :)